# Squad Size Inconsistency

Tags: xcom-2

I've built Guerilla Tactics School and noticed, that both upgrades "Squad Size I" and "Squad Size II" were available at the same time, they were worth different amount of supplies (II is more expensive), but at the same time they did the same: increased my squad size by 1.

Is it one of multiple bugs? Logically it would be correct to have "Squad Size II" available only after bying "Squad Size I".

Comment: Don't think I'd count this as a bug, but rather as a minor design oversight. You'd be a fool to selects Squad Size II over Squad Size I if both are available. Of course, it would be nice if the game would prevent you from making such mistake, but that's about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't a bug, as much as it is an unexpected order of operations.

Squad size is usually one of the things that has the highest priority. So the two levels of upgrade have a different rank requirement (= a single unit in your barracks has the needed rank).
I forget the correct ranks, I thought it was Sergeant for Size 1 and Major for Size 2.

This means there's a notable difference in the time when it's available, and you'd naturally get Size 1 first.

However, if you only built the GTS after already having a major, both options would be available.

It could've been prevented by making Size 1 a requirement for Size 2, or to have the *first* upgrade (regardless which one) cost less than the second upgrade.

However, in the end it's all the same, as you'll be meeting the requirements and paying the same cost. The only difference you would encounter is that you'd maybe pay more for the first, and then get that discount on the second. Doesn't really break the game, this just seems like a minor UI oversight.

Comment: According to the [Guerrilla Tactics School page at wikia](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Guerrilla_Tactics_School), it's "Corporal for commander difficulty and Lieutenant for legend" for Squad Size I and Captain for Squad Size II.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the Size I, but I really thought it was Major for Size II (I'm playing Commander). But I yield to the wiki :)